# Creating multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to create a multidimensional array which should have the ID and quantity from the $_POST array. At the moment it seems to put every quantity into each an element with each ID.However I want it to take the first elements from each array and then add them together to a new array and so on.

Whereas it should be

```
ID 1 - Quantity 100
ID 2 - Quantity 50
```

etc

But at the moment I get this

```
array(16) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "1"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(2) "50"
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "1"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [2]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "1"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [3]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "1"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [4]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(2) "50"
  }
  [5]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [6]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [7]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [8]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "2"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(2) "50"
  }
  [9]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "2"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [10]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "2"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [11]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "2"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [12]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "6"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(2) "50"
  }
  [13]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "6"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [14]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "6"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
  [15]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(1) "6"
    ["quantity"]=&gt;
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```

Here is my PHP code.

```
foreach($_POST['sweetids'] as $id) {

foreach($_POST['quantites'] as $quantity) {

    $stock_array[] = array(
        "id"=> $id,
        "quantity" => $quantity
        );
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show what the desired output is?

Comment: From what I see, your array is working as it should. What are you trying to get?

Comment: Can you also show the POST data?

Comment: You're iterating `$_POST['quantities']` multiple times.  I doubt that's what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
foreach($_POST['sweetids'] as $key=>$id) {

    $stock_array[] = array(
        "id"=> $id,
        "quantity" => $_POST['quantities'][$key]
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating `$_POST['quantities']` for every `$_POST['sweetids']` which is probably not what you intend.  When you iterate both, your result will be every combination of `sweetids` and `quantities`, not each *pair* of them.

I'm guessing you meant something more like:

```
// Assuming you already verified that $_POST['quantities'] and $_POST['sweetids'] exist
//   and that both of them have the same number of elements
for ( $i = 0, $len = count($_POST['sweetids']); $i < $len; $i++ ) {
    $stock_array[] = array(
        'id' => $_POST['sweetids'][$i],
        'quantity' => $_POST['quantities'][$i]
    );
}
```